# ArrayField in serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Im my model, one of my filed are ArrayField. How can I use this field in serializer class.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    arr = ArrayField(models.CharField())


class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('arr')
```

Answer (score 54):

use [**`ListField`**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield) with **`child`** argument

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    arr = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField())

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('arr',)
```

Comment: thanks for answering. but how can I pass data to arr field? Is it correct? "1,3,4,5,54,2,5,75,7,5,34,4,22,45,5,45,54,4,3,4,5,4,4,34,4,5,5,5"

Comment: I think, yes. Because It's also a *list of string*

Comment: In recent versions of DRF, you can lose `child=serializers.CharField()`, otherwise it will throw an `AssertionError`.